# How to send groovy map as a parameter in Jersey rest client Post request?

Tags: json, rest, groovy, jersey, jersey-client

I've got this code which currently sends JSON object via Jersey-client in java/groovy:

```
 webResource = client
                     .resource(endPointUrl)
                     .header("Content-Type", "application/json");
 def details = [
                name  : nameVar,
                start : startDate,
                end   : endDate,
                status: 1
                ]

 JSONObject jsonString = new JSONObject(details);

 ClientResponse response = webResource
                      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                      .header('Cookie', userCookie)
                      .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonString);
```

What I would like to do is to send that `details` map without converting it into JSONobject as I want to remove that dependency from my project. Is it possible to do? If I try `.post(ClientResponse.class, details);` it doesn't work as map is differently formatted than json. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you looked into `groovy.json.JsonBuilder()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use groovy.son.JsonBuilder as suggested by Aramiti, you might want to try something like the following:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

/**
 * Create JSON from the specified map.
 * @param map Map to convert to JSON
 * @return JSON text
 */
private buildJSONFromMap(map) {
  def builder = new JsonBuilder()

  builder {
    map.each { key, value ->
      "$key" "$value"
    }
  }

  builder.toString()
}

/**
 * Convert JSON back to map.
 * @param JSON text to convert.
 * @return Object (a map in this case)
 */
private rebuildMapFromJSON(json) {
  new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
}

def details = [
    name  : "nameVar",
    start : "startDate",
    end   : "endDate",
    status: 1
]

/* Build JSON on client side */
def json = buildJSONFromMap(details)
println("JSON: $json")

/* Consume JSON/convert to usable object */
def rebuiltMap = rebuildMapFromJSON(json)
print("Rebuilt MAP: $rebuiltMap")
```

This would produce the following in Groovy console:

```
JSON: {"name":"nameVar","start":"startDate","end":"endDate","status":"1"}
Rebuilt MAP: [status:1, start:startDate, name:nameVar, end:endDate]
```

Comment: Thanks managed to sort it out after Aramiti's comment, just going to accept your answer here